# Wait jQuery.each() until ajax call inside loop has been completed?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function in which there is a jQuery.each that iterates on all rows of a table.

The problem is that inside the each() code there is an ajax call (therefore an ajax call for each row of the table), and I want that it waits until ajax call is completed before starting with the next iteration, to make it more sequential, avoiding the possibility to start 300 ajax call at once.

Here it is a sample of my code:

```
$("button").click(function () {

    $("#table tbody tr").each(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.example.com/?param=value",
            success: function (data) {
                updateUIBasedOnResult(data);
            }
         });
    });
});
```

I know I can make the ajax call syncronous, but in this case all the UI will be blocked until the loop will ends.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't make AJAX requests in a loop - especially not 300 of them. Aggregate *all* data in to a single request then make that request *once*.

Comment: I was hoping that there were a method to do that. But if it's not possible I will follow your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used recursion to solve my problem.
I created an array of objects, where each object was representing a row in the table, and instead of the jQuery.each() loop, I passed the array to a recursive function. Basically the function makes an ajax call passing as data the first object of the array, and in the callback function I call recursively the same function removing the first element of the array, so that at each call the function makes an ajax call with a different row.

Here it is a sample code:

```
$("#creafatturebtn").click(function () {
    var rows_array = [];

    //populate rows_array

    generate(rows_array);
});

function generate(rows) {

    if (rows.length > 0) {
        varid = rows[0].id;
        var amount = rows[0].amount;

        $.get("http://api.example.com/?method=Example&id=" + id, { amount: amount }, function (data) {
            updateUIBasedOnResult(data);
            rows.shift();
            generate(rows);
        });
    }
}
```